# How do I explicitly execute default action from jQuery event

Tags: jquery, events

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094008/best-unobtrusive-way-to-add-jquery-confirm-to-an-arbitrary-element), I'm trying to implement an unobtrusive confirm dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-confirmPrompt]").click(function (event) {
        var confirmPrompt = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-confirmPrompt'].value;
        event.preventDefault();
        $.prompt(confirmPrompt, {
            buttons: { Yes: true, No: false },
            callback: function (v, m, f) {
                if (v) {
                    // User clicked Yes.  Unbind handler to avoid
                    // recursion, then click the target element again
                    $(event.currentTarget).unbind('click');
                    event.currentTarget.click();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When the user has clicked on "Yes", I want the default action associated with the event to execute.  I've done it above by unbinding the jQuery handler, and clicking the element again.  This works fine when submitting a form or navigating to a different page - but of course does not work in AJAX-enabled pages, where I want to keep the jQuery event handler.

Is there an alternative generic way to execute the default action? Logically something like `event.executeDefault()`.

Comment: A couple of ideas. 1. Make your plugin 'wrap' event handlers: $('[data-confirmPrompt]').prompt('click', function() { ... }), then you can easily unbind and rebind just one specific event handler that triggers the dialog.

Comment: 2. Set a special value on an element that would prevent prompt from firing the second time. in the top of click handler: if ($(this).data('your-flag')) { $(this).data('your-flag', 0); return true; }. Set data('your-flag', true) in the callback, and you don't need to unbind click event at all.

Comment: @Alexey - thanks, I'd been thinking about your solution 2 - using a flag like what we used to do in the old days to prevent re-entrancy in VB event handlers. I'll probably go with it if no-one comes up with anything more elegant.

Comment: Clearly this question is quite old, but for posterity, here's a suggestion. Use `.on('click',` and `.off('click')` instead of `.click` and `.unbind('click')`. Then add a namespace to the event, like so: `.on('click.confirm',`.  Then, when removing the handler, use the same namespace -- `.off('click.confirm')`.  This unbinds only the handler that you just registered, instead of all jquery handlers -- suspect that your Ajax calls will still work. This should work as of jquery 1.7.

Comment: I think the way to do it is to prevent event bubbling (`event.stopPropagation()`,and then `return true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the suggestion Alexey Lebedev made in his second comment, my current implementation now looks like the sample below, except that I've also added my own implementation of localization for the button labels.

Notes:

- I'm now using a jqueryUI dialog widget
- Note the use of .delegate so that the handler is "ajax-aware", i.e. works on elements added to the DOM after the page is loaded, e.g. as a result of an AJAX call
- Uses a flag to prevent recursion when the user clicks Yes on the confirm dialog.
- Uses jquery 1.6.4 and jquery-ui-1.8.16

If anyone can suggest improvements, please chime in.

```
<!-- Examples of usage -->
<input type='submit' data-confirm="OK to delete customer 123?" ... />
<a href="..." data-confirm="OK to navigate?" ... />

<!-- Implementation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var confirmClickHandler = function (event) {
        if ($(event.currentTarget).data('isConfirming')) return;
        var message = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-confirm'].value;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<div></div>')
                .html(message)
                .dialog({
                    title: "Confirm",
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $(event.currentTarget).data('isConfirming', true);
                            event.currentTarget.click();
                            $(event.currentTarget).data('isConfirming', null);
                        },
                        "No": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true
                });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").delegate("[data-confirm]", "click", confirmClickHandler);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing something similar and this works fine for me:

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to asdf?')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but the problem with the javascript confirm is that as long as it's displayed, the user can't interact with any other tabs on a tabbed browser.  The jQuery prompt that I use is modal for the current page, but the user can still switch to other tabs.

Comment: @Joe That's a problem that you shouldn't worry about. Some browsers don't actually do this (I think iOS don't).

Comment: What if you want to add a formatted paragraph to confirm, and user must read before responding with yes or no??

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if this answers your question, but it might help a bit.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<button onclick="alert('Hello world!');" class="btn">Test 1</button>
<button onclick="alert(this.className);" class="btn">Test 2</button>
```

I've added the following to my `$(document).ready`:

```
$('button').each(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var onClick = btn.attr('onclick');

    //replace this with _this
    onClick = onClick.replace(/this/g, "_this");

    btn.attr('onclick', '');

    btn.click(function() {
        if (confirm('Do it?')) {

            //set _this first!
            var _this = btn[0];

            eval(onClick);
        }
    });
});
```

It seems to get the job done. Check this jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/4jThg/.

**EDIT**
I've created something that looks more like your question: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/hqLH5/. Just couldn't figure out which $.prompt plugin your were using, so I grabbed the first one I've found from [github](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu) (this one only works in Chrome :S).

Comment: your solution seems to be specifically dealing with a confirmation for an onclick handler - I'm looking for something more general, so it doesn't really answer the question.  See my own answer for the best solution I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by calling `event.stopPropagation()` from a more specific context, and ensuring that I *don't* call `event.preventDefault()`. While you can't call the default action *explicitly*, you can set up the conditions so that the default action happens — and do as little or as much else as you wish.

```
    // Normal event handler
    $("[data-toggle]").click(ev => {
      switchToTab(ev.currentTarget)
      ev.preventDefault()
    })

    // Allow default handler in a specific case.
    $("[data-toggle] ul a").click(ev => {
      // Don't bubble the event to the less specific handler, above
      ev.stopPropagation()
      // An incorrect return value will also cancel the default action.
      return true
    })
```