# Before deleting a row in repeater , i want to do validation asking that, are sure you want to delete..?How can i do this?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i want to do validation asking that, are sure you want to delete..?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server"  
           CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>' OnCommand="Calling_Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to use Confirm Button extender. Just drag this control next to the linkbutton and set the Confirmbutton externders TargetControlID to the Id of the Linkbutton. Everything else will be taken care of by the control.

More info- http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx

Comment: It even works fine in datbound controls like repeaters, gridviews etc.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135983/13087) has one way to do it, using jQuery and [a jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

One advantage of using a javascript dialog such as that provided by jQuery UI is that the popup dialog is modal only for the web page on which it is displayed.  You can still access other tabs within your browser while the popup is displayed.

Other solutions that use the javascript `confirm` function will force the user to dismiss the confirmation dialog before switching to another browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx) property to attach the java-script that will do the prompting. For example,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" 
     CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>' 
     OnClientClick="return confirm('Are sure you want to delete..?');"
     OnCommand="Calling_Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: @user1240045, seems to be your first question on SO. If your problem is solved then you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick-mark at the left side of answer. See SO FAQ for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

if u'd like to use custom confirmation ( like jquery dialog,bootboxjs etc.. ) then you have to generate button's "postback string" or get it somehow. asp.net gives such as postback name after rendering the page; **__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDeleteSelected','')**. after realizing this i wrote a js function which is generates button's postback str;

```
function PostBackBtnMake(id) { // id : ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDeleteSelected
var result;
var temp = id.split('_');
result = 'ctl00$' + temp[0] + '$' + temp[1];
return result;
```

}

then i be able to use in custom confirmation box (in this case i used bootboxjs);

```
function PostBackBtn(e) {
var _result = false;
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
    if (result) {
        __doPostBack(PostBackBtnMake(e.id), '')
    }
});

return _result;
```

}

it's worked for me, i hope it helps you too.