# Jquery Submit not work

Tags: jquery, .net, partial-views

I have a function that was originally working for `$(form).submit()`. I had to modify it to work on `$("#savebutton").click()` because there is already a form.sumbit() function in the main view. The only problem is that the form stopped submitting when the button is clicked and the state is valid.
Old Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
});

function showMsg(hasCurrentJob) {
    if (hasCurrentJob == "True") {
        alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
        return false;
    } else {
       $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
    }
}
```

CurrentCode

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#saveButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "Shared")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });

    function showMsg(hasCurrentJob) {
        if (hasCurrentJob == "True") {
            alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
            return false;
        } else {
            $("form").submit();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

***Update(Still not working)***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#saveButton").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).data('shouldSubmit')) return;
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "Shared")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data, e);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });

    function showMsg(hasCurrentJob, e) {
        if (hasCurrentJob == "True") {
            alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
            return false;
        } else {
            $(e.currentTarget).data('shouldSubmit', true);
            $("#saveButton").click();
            $(e.currentTarget).data('shouldSubmit', null);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135983/13087) uses a technique which might work.  Basically click the same button again programatically, and use a flag to determine if it's being clicked inside the confirmation method (`showMsg` in your case).

Comment: I'm having a hard following that but did make attempt. Will post above. Please let me know if you see anything.

Comment: @atbyrd, I don't see anything obvious wrong with your updated version.  I suggest you try stepping through it with a debugger.