# why "return false;" or "event.preDefualt();" doesn't work after $.post();?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why "return false;" or "event.preDefualt();" doesn't work after $.post();
Firstly,I simply written a return false after
 `$(#id).submit(function(e){ return false;}// it works properly`.But 
when i call something via `$.post('check-email.php',{parameter},function{data})` and i try to write return false after that $.post call.It doesn't works and directly goes to next page.
 here is my code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () { //newly added 
    $('#mysignupform').submit(function (event) {
        return false;
        or event.preDfault(); // only work here
        var emailVal = $('#inputEmail').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
        //alert(emailVal);
        $.post('check-email.php', {
            'email': emailVal
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == 'false') {
                $("#mysignupform").submit(function (event) {
                    return false;
                    or event.preventDefault(); //both doesnt work here..why??
                    ;
                });
            } else {
                $("#mysingupform").submit(function () {
                    return false;
                }); //retrun false doesnt work here..why??
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I dont want to allow them to submit but still its happening. Please help me..!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: do not use unrelated tags. PHP removed.

Comment: Don't know if this is a 3-times typo, but it's ```event.preventDefault()```

Comment: what you getting in data

Comment: You're already inside the submit event and you're creating two more events I don't get it... A return statement won't return an outer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //newly added 
    $('#mysignupform').submit(function (event) {
        // your $.post call
        $.post('check-email.php', {email: emailVal}, function (data) {
            // ...
            // having a return false means returning false to the success callback
            // of your .post call. it is not the same as returning false to the 
            // submit() callback
        });

        // return false to submit()
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$.post` is *asynchronous*. Execution continues at the statement following the call to `$.post` immediately. Since there isn't a statement following it, the `submit` event handler function will simply return `undefined` and the browser will happily continue with the submit as if nothing happened.

The callback to asynchronous methods will only be executed some time later. In your case, that will be when the server returns a response. Since the outer function has already returned, there is nowhere for that callback function to return *to*.

You will need to always prevent the default action in a `click` event handler on the form submit button, and then re-submit the form programatically upon success in the `$.post` callback:

```
$('#mysignupform :submit').click(function (event) {
    var form = this.closest("form"); // Get a reference to the containing form
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action (form submission)
    $.post('check-email.php', { /* data */ }, function (data) {
        // If the data is good...
        form.submit(); // Submit the containing form
    });
});
```

Obviously you can't really do this if you're binding to the form `submit` event, since the re-submission of the form will trigger the event handler again and you'll be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax works asynchronous. The easy solution is bind a click event handler on the submit button.

```
$('#your_submit_button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailVal = $('#inputEmail').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
    $.post('check-email.php', {
        'email': emailVal
    }, function (data) {
        if (data !== 'false') {
            // submit the form here
            $("#mysingupform").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.post(...)` is asynchronous. Try `$.ajax(async: false, ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function that is executed after the post completes is executed asynchronously, i.e. you are no longer in the event handler.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105556/how-do-i-explicitly-execute-default-action-from-jquery-event) has a technique you can use - basically click the submit button again, after setting a Boolean flag to prevent your post logic from being executed twice.